# Dotnetnuke - How to write server side script in skin.ascx file

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

I am extremely new to dotnetnuke. I don't know which server side language can write in Dotnetnuke skin.ascx page. How to write server side script in skin.ascx file?

Answer (score 4):

just use `<% %>` same as normal .aspx./ascx page, for example:

```
<%
DotNetNuke.Framework.jQuery.RequestRegistration()
%>
```

just use the syntax of vb or c# whatever you are using

Answer (score 4):

Or alternatively use this. Also works with VB or C#

```
  <script runat="server">
  Protected Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init

  'do something'

  End Sub
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a skin object which is similar to a user control see the link below for a simple example that adds hello to the login users name

http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/DevelopingandImplementingDNNSkinObjects.aspx